# Pivot Table returns wrong value on one row

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have a very strange problem. I built a macro that refreshes several PivotTables. Everything is fine except for one PivotTable where one value "AGHF21A#BFF" in the source gets changed into "54r" in the Pivot Table. Other PivotTables also get data from this source and they all get the correct value. This only happens with this specific case from a list of 30 products, this is the only one that changes the value in the Pivot Table. 
I tried everything Excel would allow me do. I changed the format to string/general. I tried to do a calculated field. The strange thing is that if in the source data I add let's say any character, remove any character or change any character then the pivot table does recognize the code and does not change it to the strange code "54r." I have never seen any Pivot table do this before.
The Macro downloads different reports into Excel and then it refreshes the PivotTables. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: This will be difficult to figure out without the actual workbook to look at...